# Python Kivy Screen Inheritance

Tags: android, python, inheritance, screen, kivy

Background: I am using solely Python to implement the Kivy screens. I have two screens that both contain a list, and two rows of buttons. I thought it would be good programming practice to create a screen class that has those layouts, and then use inheritance to create the two screens and add buttons to the layouts as needed.

The Problem: However, when I do this I find that in the child screens I cannot access self.manager.current <-- specifically '.current' It also does not have access to self.manager.transition. I wish to understand why this happens, and how/what things are inherited here.

Question: Does anybody know why or how it is not inheriting the parent screen's manager's properties?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.listview import ListView, ListItemButton
from kivy.adapters import listadapter
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition


class ListScreen(Screen): # This is the super class that I am trying to inherit through
    itemList = ListProperty([])
    selected_value = StringProperty()
    layout = BoxLayout(orientation ='vertical')
    top_buttons=BoxLayout(size_hint_y=0.1)
    scrollable_list=ListView(adapter=listadapter, size_hint_y=0.8)
    scrollable_list.data=itemList
    scrollable_list.selection_mode='single'
    scrollable_list.allow_empty_selection=False
    # scrollable_list.cls=ListItemButton <-- Unrelated bug here, ignore this line
    bot_buttons=BoxLayout(size_hint_y=0.1)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ListScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def finalize_widgets(self):
        self.layout.add_widget(self.top_buttons)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.scrollable_list)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.bot_buttons)
        self.add_widget(self.layout)

    def change(self,change):
        self.selected_value = 'Selected: {}'.format(change.text)

    def change_screen(self, screen_name):
        self.manager.current = screen_name # <-- Here is the problem


class SubScreen(ListScreen):
# This is one of the child classes, intended to inherit Screen through the parent ListScreen class.

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SubScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        save = Button(text='Save')
        load = Button(text='Load')
        new_d = Button(text='New')
        new_s = Button(text='New Search')

        self.top_buttons.add_widget(save)
        self.top_buttons.add_widget(load)
        self.top_buttons.add_widget(new_d)
        self.top_buttons.add_widget(new_s)

        new_s.bind(on_press = self.change_screen('search'))


class ListBuilderApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager(transition=SlideTransition())
        sm.add_widget(SubScreen(name='list'))
        sm.add_widget(SearchResults(name='results'))
        sm.add_widget(SearchScreen(name='search'))
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ListBuilderApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't see `ScreenManager` which is basically what you get with `self.manager`(object), so...

No `ScreenManager` with Screens added either in python or kv like widgets(`add_widget()`), no `self.manager` inside any of the `Screens` - you can't access something that isn't there.

Add some class which will be a root for your Screens and make it `ScreenManager` + add Screens as children.

**Edit:**
I was blind probably, but I didn't see `on_press=..` stuff. There is the problem, because you didn't assign the function to an event, rather *called* the function right when you put `('search')` at the end. (try do `self.parent` and you'll see)

Kivy events(at least "on_") catch the function, but not the parameters, not directly. That's why you need to use `partial`

```
from functools import partial
new_s.bind(on_press = partial(self.change_screen,'search'))
```

With this the error is gone, but some adapter binding jumps out which I really don't have a clue how to fix as I don't use it that much.

Comment: Terribly sorry, I do have that class, I have edited the question to include the class. It still has the same problem as stated in the question.

Comment: Thank you! I will spend some time messing around with that. I was also able to parially fix the problem by putting manager=sm in the parameters for the screens as I added them to sm with add_widget(). Do you think it would be better to just make the screens in the manager class as two copies of ListScreen() with different names and then just add the buttons there?

Comment: Scratch that, re-setting manager did not work , I should not have tried that XD I tried using partial and I see what you mean about adapter binding. I think I am just going to create two separate screen classes that contain similar code, no matter what I try inheritance does not seem to be working well.